# Safely serving other people's PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache, security, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon ec2 instance (linux).

I'd like you (yes, you) to be able to upload a PHP file and then serve it live on www.mydomain.com/yourname. I'd also like to be able to do this for numerous other people (www.mydomain.com/theirname).

I'm worried that you (or they, let's not point fingers) could do malicious things (purposefully or accidentally). For example, an infinite loop, reading/writing outside of one's root directory, taking the server down, running system commands, etc. This is what I would try if I wanted to be malicious.

Is there any way to set up PHP/apache/user permissions, or maybe search through their code before serving it, so that being malicious would at least be much, much harder?

Comment: I'd say there's no such thing as absolute security so a good rule of thumb is to run user supplied code on a different server than the one your main application is running on. Also, it's a good idea to have a load balancing server to go with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Among other things, you'll definitely want to adjust your PHP.ini to include this:

```
disable_functions =exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source
```

This will prevent the execution of those functions within any PHP files that utilize this .ini

I would also enable [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) support to lock down users to within their own directories so they can't use something like:

`require_once '../../another_user/index.php';`

or

`$notMyFile = file_get_contents('../../another_user/config.php');`

Answer (score 5):

There's no bulletproof way of doing this.

First of all, no syscalls.

Secondly, timeout for each script.

And, you'll probably also want to keep a outside "quit button" in your hands so you can pull the plug if you see something going wrong.

PHP is a very large language, and having others run code on your server is a *very* difficult thing to do safely.

Comment: Which is why you should probably just allocate a separate VM to each user/script, and destroy the VM when you're done.

Comment: I can still hammer the hell out of the VM and push up your usage a ton so that EC2 bills will kill you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Runkit Sandbox

> Instantiating the Runkit_Sandbox class creates a new thread with its own scope and program stack. Using a set of options passed to the constructor, this environment may be restricted to a subset of what the primary interpreter can do and provide a safer environment for executing user supplied code.

http://php.net/manual/en/runkit.sandbox.php

Keep in mind that any resources you provide to a sandboxed environment can and eventually will be abused.  If users should not be able to affect each other's results, for example, and you do provide users with a database, give each a different database in their sandbox with different credentials.